# Types of simple Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

What exactly is Simple algebra of type $A_2$?
I found that it has something to do with root systems, which I also don't really know what those are. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't understand what is the definition. Specifically I need to prove that $sl(3,\mathbb R)$ is $A_2$.

Comment: This is done in the duplicate, see the comments there: $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$, the Lie algebra of traceless $3\times 3$-matrices, is determined by its Cartan numbers, which are exactly the ones of $A_2$. Or said otherwise: Lie algebras of type $A_n$ are just the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{sl}(n+1)$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: It is best to first post a Question about the definition of something, rather than charging ahead with a problem centering on a definition you do not understand.  When you ask a Question, Readers need to rely on you to know what it is you are asking.